# How do I scroll back to top in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I have a WebView control in RelativeLayout. Sometimes Html is longer then display, so user can 'scroll' to the bottom. I want to add a button that would scroll back to top of the screen. But I'm not able to find any proper way to do this.

This button would also float at the bottom, that's why I'm using relative layout.

WebView neither RelativeLayout have property where I could scroll to top in my code-behind.

Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: You might need to inject JavaScript into the page and create an HTML button to do the scrolling for you. Not sure that there is a way to programmatically scroll the WebView from the Xamarin code. But you could also create a Xamarin Forms button on your page which, when clicked, called JavaScript in the page and told it to scroll to the top. That might work better for your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the WebView.Eval method. It's very simple, something like this would do:

```
MyButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => { MyWebView.Eval("window.scrollTo(0, 0)"); };
```